# Pymongo can not perform aggregating with pipeline in too large collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have billions records in  `patients colletion`,
I have no idea how could I filter it with pipeline.

Or this is a limit on mongoDB, we couldn't  aggregate with pipeline on large collection ?

I've already add `allowDiskUse=True`  option, but it doesn't work too.

How could I  get the filtered result by the pipeline ?

How could I simply store the filtered result into another collection ? Thanks

## Sample code (I use `pymongo` so the follows are in Python syntax )

```
import datetime
pipeline = [
        {"$project": {"birthday":1, "id":1}
    },
    {
             "$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)} }    
     },{"$group": ~~~
     }
    ]
res =db.patients.aggregate(pipeline,allowDiskUse=True)
```

## Exception Message

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'patients'), ('pipeline', [{'$match': {'birthday': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}}]), ('allowDiskUse', True)]) on namespace tw_insurance_security_development.$cmd failed: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)
```

How

Comment: Looks like you're using a version of MongoDB before aggregations returned cursors. Upgrade to >= 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Store your result in a `collection`, then do another aggregation pass on it. It's a limitation of `mongo`, you can read more about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

Comment: How could I simply store the filtered result into another collection ? Thanks

Comment: As a last step in the aggregation pipeline add an [`out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for an app with a human-based UI then I would suggest using paging -- by way of mongo's skip and limit and also restricting fields to those viewable by said human (which you seem to be doing with the $project).

"I have no idea how could I filter it with pipeline." 
Try the following

```
i_Limit = 100 # Or whatever value plays nice
cnt_Skip = 0
has_Next = True

while has_Next:

         pipe = [{"$project": {"birthday":1, "id":1}},{"$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}}, {$skip: cnt_Skip},{$limit: i_Limit}, {"$group": ~~~ }]   

        cursor =db.patients.aggregate(pipe,allowDiskUse=True)

        if not cursor:
            has_Next = False
            continue

        for record in cursor:

            # Do whatever needed with the record
            print record



        cnt_Skip = cnt_Skip + i_Limit
```

If doing a big dump then use `mongoexport`.